# Copy from clipboard and replace the html using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, clipboard

I am copying formated documents from word.When i alert this using javascript i am getting html tag.So now i want to replace all the list tags `(<li>)` with list underscore `<li>-`.Here is my code.Friends can you explain why it is not working as expected.

```
<div>        
    <textarea id="txtid"> </textarea>
</div>
<div ></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //put yer code in here

        ['paste'].forEach(function(event) {
            document.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var pastedText = undefined;

                if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE    
                    pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');    
                } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {    
                    pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');    
                }    

                var someString = pastedText;
                var anotherString = someString.replace(/<li>/g, '<li>-');
                alert(anotherString);
            });
        });    
    });    
</script>
```

The sample text is [image: sample text looks like this]

fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/user1989/8hkdgLox/3/
This is working only in google chrome

Comment: can you provide your sample text that you are trying to replace

Comment: Gosh not image dude, give raw sample data

Comment: @n01ze sorry   input looks like that .Stackoverflow also doesn't allow to post input.It is  taking away bullets. i need to replace bullets with hyphen.

Comment: Insert the raw data , and select it and than press "cntrl" + "k"

Comment: @n01ze The edit tab of stackoverflow doent allow to paste contents with bullets.it is deleting that formated bullets

Comment: you type those input in msoffice.Then copy it.Then paste the content in the textarea of the html page

Comment: I think the problem is that your paste is not creating `<li>` tags. It's just producing those dingbat Unicode characters in your text field. If it's an option, you're better off converting from Word format to HTML using `pandoc` or something. What is this a part of?

Comment: @NighttimeDriver50000 But when i try to alert it it is showing <li> tags..

Comment: Ah. I do not know then.

Comment: i have seen your code it doesn't work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gs7naedo/ i have done some thing that alerts the clipboard content **it just doesn't contain what you said <li>** the content of the clipboard is either raw if i use `event.originalEvent.clipboard.getData("text")` or when we call `event.originalEvent.clipboard.getData("text/html")`  it contains some xml content that uses microsoft namespace wich again **doesn't contain <li>**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see after copying and alerting equivalent document from Office 2013 it content is much bigger than list. Browser is showing only body tag.
I recommend you parse the result.

My example content:

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">    
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 15">
<link rel=File-List
href="Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_filelist.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <o:AllowPNG/>
 </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
<link rel=themeData
href="Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_themedata.thmx">
<link rel=colorSchemeMapping
href="Local\Temp\msohtmlclip1\01\clip_colorschememapping.xml">
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Normal</w:View>
  <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
  <w:TrackMoves/>
  <w:TrackFormatting/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>
  <w:ValidateAgainstSchemas/>
  <w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>false</w:SaveIfXMLInvalid>
  <w:IgnoreMixedContent>false</w:IgnoreMixedContent>
  <w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>false</w:AlwaysShowPlaceholderText>
  <w:DoNotPromoteQF/>
  <w:LidThemeOther>EN-US</w:LidThemeOther>
  <w:LidThemeAsian>X-NONE</w:LidThemeAsian>
  <w:LidThemeComplexScript>X-NONE</w:LidThemeComplexScript>
  <w:Compatibility>
   <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
   <w:SnapToGridInCell/>
   <w:WrapTextWithPunct/>
   <w:UseAsianBreakRules/>
   <w:DontGrowAutofit/>
   <w:SplitPgBreakAndParaMark/>
   <w:EnableOpenTypeKerning/>
   <w:DontFlipMirrorIndents/>
   <w:OverrideTableStyleHps/>
  </w:Compatibility>
  <m:mathPr>
   <m:mathFont m:val="Cambria Math"/>
   <m:brkBin m:val="before"/>
   <m:brkBinSub m:val="&#45;-"/>
   <m:smallFrac m:val="off"/>
   <m:dispDef/>
   <m:lMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:rMargin m:val="0"/>
   <m:defJc m:val="centerGroup"/>
   <m:wrapIndent m:val="1440"/>
   <m:intLim m:val="subSup"/>
   <m:naryLim m:val="undOvr"/>
  </m:mathPr></w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:LatentStyles DefLockedState="false" DefUnhideWhenUsed="false"
  DefSemiHidden="false" DefQFormat="false" DefPriority="99"
  LatentStyleCount="371">
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="0" QFormat="true" Name="Normal"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" QFormat="true" Name="heading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="9" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="heading 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 7"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 8"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="toc 9"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Normal Indent"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="footnote text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="annotation text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="header"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="footer"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="index heading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="35" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="caption"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="table of figures"/>      
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="List Number 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="10" QFormat="true" Name="Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Closing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Signature"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="Default Paragraph Font"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Body Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Outline List 3"/>      
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" Name="Table Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" UnhideWhenUsed="true"
   Name="Table Theme"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" Name="Placeholder Text"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="1" QFormat="true" Name="No Spacing"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" Name="Light Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" Name="Light List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" Name="Light Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" Name="Medium Shading 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" Name="Medium Shading 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" Name="Medium List 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" Name="Medium List 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" Name="Medium Grid 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" Name="Medium Grid 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" Name="Medium Grid 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" Name="Dark List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" Name="Colorful Shading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" Name="Colorful List"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" Name="Colorful Grid"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" Name="Light Shading Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" Name="Light List Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" Name="Light Grid Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" SemiHidden="true" Name="Revision"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="34" QFormat="true"
   Name="List Paragraph"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="29" QFormat="true" Name="Quote"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="30" QFormat="true"
   Name="Intense Quote"/>      
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" Name="Light List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" Name="Light Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" Name="Dark List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" Name="Colorful List Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" Name="Light Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="61" Name="Light List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="62" Name="Light Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="63" Name="Medium Shading 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="64" Name="Medium Shading 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="65" Name="Medium List 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="66" Name="Medium List 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="67" Name="Medium Grid 1 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="68" Name="Medium Grid 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="69" Name="Medium Grid 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="70" Name="Dark List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="71" Name="Colorful Shading Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="72" Name="Colorful List Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="60" Name="Light Shading Accent 6"/>      
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="73" Name="Colorful Grid Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="19" QFormat="true"
   Name="Subtle Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="21" QFormat="true"
   Name="Intense Emphasis"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="31" QFormat="true"
   Name="Subtle Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="32" QFormat="true"
   Name="Intense Reference"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="33" QFormat="true" Name="Book Title"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="37" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" Name="Bibliography"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="39" SemiHidden="true"
   UnhideWhenUsed="true" QFormat="true" Name="TOC Heading"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="41" Name="Plain Table 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="42" Name="Plain Table 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="43" Name="Plain Table 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="44" Name="Plain Table 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="45" Name="Plain Table 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="40" Name="Grid Table Light"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46" Name="Grid Table 1 Light"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="Grid Table 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="Grid Table 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="Grid Table 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="Grid Table 5 Dark"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51" Name="Grid Table 6 Colorful"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52" Name="Grid Table 7 Colorful"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="Grid Table 1 Light Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="Grid Table 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="Grid Table 3 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="Grid Table 4 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="Grid Table 7 Colorful Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="Grid Table 1 Light Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="Grid Table 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="Grid Table 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="Grid Table 4 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="Grid Table 6 Colorful Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="Grid Table 7 Colorful Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="Grid Table 1 Light Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="Grid Table 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="Grid Table 3 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="Grid Table 4 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="Grid Table 5 Dark Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="Grid Table 6 Colorful Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="Grid Table 7 Colorful Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46" Name="List Table 1 Light"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51" Name="List Table 6 Colorful"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52" Name="List Table 7 Colorful"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 1"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 2"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 3"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 4"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 5"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="46"
   Name="List Table 1 Light Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="47" Name="List Table 2 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="48" Name="List Table 3 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="49" Name="List Table 4 Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="50" Name="List Table 5 Dark Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="51"
   Name="List Table 6 Colorful Accent 6"/>
  <w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="52"
   Name="List Table 7 Colorful Accent 6"/>
 </w:LatentStyles>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Wingdings;
    panose-1:5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    mso-font-charset:2;
    mso-generic-font-family:auto;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:0 268435456 0 0 -2147483648 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:roman;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-536870145 1107305727 0 0 415 0;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
    mso-font-charset:0;
    mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
    mso-font-pitch:variable;
    mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073786111 1 0 415 0;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
p.MsoListParagraph, li.MsoListParagraph, div.MsoListParagraph
    {mso-style-priority:34;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-add-space:auto;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst
    {mso-style-priority:34;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-type:export-only;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-add-space:auto;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle
    {mso-style-priority:34;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-type:export-only;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-add-space:auto;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
p.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, li.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast, div.MsoListParagraphCxSpLast
    {mso-style-priority:34;
    mso-style-unhide:no;
    mso-style-qformat:yes;
    mso-style-type:export-only;
    margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:0in;
    margin-left:.5in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-add-space:auto;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    mso-default-props:yes;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-fareast-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";
    mso-bidi-theme-font:minor-bidi;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;
    mso-header-margin:.5in;
    mso-footer-margin:.5in;
    mso-paper-source:0;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
 /* List Definitions */
 @list l0
    {mso-list-id:927886268;
    mso-list-type:hybrid;
    mso-list-template-ids:-613886464 67698699 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693 67698689 67698691 67698693;}
@list l0:level1
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Wingdings;}
@list l0:level2
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:o;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:"Courier New";}
@list l0:level3
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Wingdings;}
@list l0:level4
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Symbol;}
@list l0:level5
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:o;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:"Courier New";}
@list l0:level6
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Wingdings;}
@list l0:level7
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Symbol;}
@list l0:level8
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:o;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:"Courier New";}
@list l0:level9
    {mso-level-number-format:bullet;
    mso-level-text:;
    mso-level-tab-stop:none;
    mso-level-number-position:left;
    text-indent:-.25in;
    font-family:Wingdings;}
ol
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
ul
    {margin-bottom:0in;}
-->
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 10]>
<style>
 /* Style Definitions */
 table.MsoNormalTable
    {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
    mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
    mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
    mso-style-noshow:yes;
    mso-style-priority:99;
    mso-style-parent:"";
    mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
    mso-para-margin:0in;
    mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    mso-ascii-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-ascii-theme-font:minor-latin;
    mso-hansi-font-family:Calibri;
    mso-hansi-theme-font:minor-latin;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>    
<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<!--StartFragment-->

<p class=MsoNormal>This is a test resume part<o:p></o:p></p>    
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
style='font-family:Wingdings;mso-fareast-font-family:Wingdings;mso-bidi-font-family:
Wingdings'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>Ø<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]>Line1<o:p></o:p></p>    
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
style='font-family:Wingdings;mso-fareast-font-family:Wingdings;mso-bidi-font-family:
Wingdings'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>Ø<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]>Line2<o:p></o:p></p>    
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
style='font-family:Wingdings;mso-fareast-font-family:Wingdings;mso-bidi-font-family:
Wingdings'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>Ø<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]>Line3<o:p></o:p></p>    
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpLast style='text-indent:-.25in;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span
style='font-family:Wingdings;mso-fareast-font-family:Wingdings;mso-bidi-font-family:
Wingdings'><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>Ø<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;
</span></span></span><![endif]>Line4<o:p></o:p></p>    
<!--EndFragment-->
</body>    
</html>
```